# jquery range-slider not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Slider functionality</title>

    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#slider-3").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 24,
                values: [9, 18],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#price").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
                }
            });
            $("#price").val( $("#slider-3").slider("values", 0) + ":00" +
                " - " + $("#slider-3").slider("values", 1) + ":00");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <p>
        <label for="price">Email Working Timeframe</label>
        <input type="text" id="price"
               style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>
    <div id="slider-3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The slider does not appear when I run the code/

I've the code on jsfiddle and it works fine, but I'm not sure why it's not working when I run it myself.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Slider functionality</title>

    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#slider-3").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 24,
                values: [9, 18],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#price").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
                }
            });
            $("#price").val( $("#slider-3").slider("values", 0) + ":00" +
                " - " + $("#slider-3").slider("values", 1) + ":00");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <p>
        <label for="price">Email Working Timeframe</label>
        <input type="text" id="price"
               style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>
    <div id="slider-3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only output I get is "Email Working Timeframe"

Comment: It very hard to help you debug the problem if it can't be reproduced here. You code and everything runs rune when I try it. I suggest that you check the console log and see if it returns any errors.

Comment: working fine check now, no required any changes

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So I pasted the code above in one single html file and it should be working, right? Btw, I'm doing this in c# visual studio, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Please try according to the below script. it is working properly.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Slider functionality</title>

    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <p>
        <label for="price">Email Working Timeframe</label>
        <input type="text" id="price"
               style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
    </p>
    <div id="slider-3"></div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#slider-3").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 24,
                values: [9, 18],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#price").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
                }
            });
            $("#price").val( $("#slider-3").slider("values", 0) + ":00" +
                " - " + $("#slider-3").slider("values", 1) + ":00");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. So I pasted the code above in one single html file and it should be working, right? Btw, I'm doing this in c# visual studio, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. So the problem was in the Layout.html file which was calling(@RenderBody()) my index.html(the code above). The Layout.html was doing @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") and I was making another jquery link in the index.html which was redundant and the the jquery that I needed was not able to link.